# "Impatience won" vs "impatience won out"

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the two? Which one should I choose in a sentence like this:

> I was waiting outside of the house, but, again, impatience won (out). So I went inside to get her.

Comment: add some more context. What's this? I'm not getting!

Comment: @Maulik V How about now?

Comment: what makes you think adding 'out'? Do you see any specific need?

Comment: @Maulik V I saw it on Google: https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22Again+impatience+won%22&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=icxBVd-THofHmwWE5YGYBA

Comment: *won out* seems a strange use to me. I'll certainly not use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both versions, they will convey a similar meaning.

According to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/win) the verb **win** has the following meaning:

> 1. To achieve victory or finish first in a competition.
> 2. To achieve success in an effort or venture.

As you can see here we need the intransitive usage.

Adding the preposition **out** it becomes a phrasal verb with the meaning:

> To succeed or prevail.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition "out" with certain verbs expresses the idea of *completeness*  or *completedness*.

**When the scaffolding *gave out*, the workers fell.

Cooler heads did not *win out*, and the situation degenerated into violence.

The explorers *ran out* of provisions and had to eat their dogs.**

Comment: But _run out_ and _won out_ don't necessarily follow the same rules. Sometime the _out_ can be struck (like in the O.P.'s example), but that's not the case in your sentence about starving explorers.